# How does ursina engine detect if the update function is declared?

Tags: python

I've been trying to emulate Ursina Game Engine's update method by defining it

main_game.py

```
from testengine import *


def update():
    pass


def draw():
    pass


game = game(900, 500, 'Game', 60)
game.run()
```

__init__.py

```
import pygame


class game():
    WIN = None
    run = False

def __init__(self, WIDTH, HEIGHT, TITLE, FPS):
    self.WIDTH = WIDTH
    self.HEIGHT = HEIGHT
    self.TITLE = TITLE
    self.FPS = FPS
    WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)

def run(self):
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    global update, draw
    while run:
        clock.tick(self.FPS)
        update()
        draw()
```

I tried importing `main_game.py` but it turns into a circular import.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
try:
    update
except NameError:
    print("the function update() doesn't exist")
else:
    print("the function update exist")
```